# Testing for stepUp and stepDown method support

Tags: javascript

In Firefox 28.0, I get this error : **InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable** with the following code when pressing one of the buttons.

How do I correctly test if the browser supports stepUp and stedDown methods before using them?

```
<input id="input0" type="number" value="100" step="5">
<button onClick="up();">stepUp</button>
<button onClick="down();">stepDown</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var input0 = document.getElementById('input0');

   function up() {

      'use strict';

      if (typeof input0.stepUp === 'function') {

         input0.stepUp();

      }

   }

   function down() {

      'use strict';

      if (typeof input0.stepDown === 'function') {

         input0.stepDown();

      }

   }

</script>
```

Try http://jsfiddle.net/GtHV6/ open the browser console and press one of the buttons to get the error.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does it work in, for example, Chrome (as it does for me)?

Comment: Working perfectly in Firefox 29.0a2 (closest I could find). If it really doesn't work in 28, it's a bug.

Comment: Also IE11 says **InvalidStateError**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there seems to be a bug. I've made the following for you:

```
   var input0 = document.getElementById('input0');

   function up() {

      'use strict';

      if (typeof input0.stepUp === 'function') {
          try{
         input0.stepUp();
          }catch(ex){
          var step=Number(input0.step);
              input0.value = Number(input0.value) + step;
          }
      }

   }

   function down() {

      'use strict';

      if (typeof input0.stepDown === 'function') {
          try{
         input0.stepDown();
          }catch(ex){
          var step=Number(input0.step);
              input0.value = Number(input0.value) - step;
          }
      }

   }
```

The `ex` contains the string `InvalidStateError`.

The above will work cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function step(formField, direction) {

    function stepFallback(formField, direction) {
        var directionModifier = direction === 'down' ? -1 : 1,
            step = Number(formField.getAttribute('step'));
        formField.value = Number(formField.value) + (step * directionModifier);
    }

    if (typeof formField.stepUp === 'function' && typeof formField.stepDown === 'function') {
        // We have stepUp/stepDown support
        try {
            // But need a try/catch as support is buggy or partial in e.g. Safari
            if (direction === 'down') {
                formField.stepDown();
            } else {
                formField.stepUp();
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            stepFallback(formField, direction);
        }
    } else {
        // No stepUp/stepDown support: use fallback
        stepFallback(formField, direction);
    }
}
```